# Inheritance and virtual member functions

Tags: c++

I am not 100% sure the outcome that would occur in my current setup up.

This maybe a stupid question, but I can not see a similar example.

Here is the example code

```
Class A {

  public:
    virtual Steer* getSomeParticularInfo(){ return m_steer; }

  private:
    Steer* m_steer:
}


Class B: A {

  public:
    virtual Steer* getSomeParticularInfo(){ return m_steer; }

  private:
    Steer* m_steer:
}

Class C: B {

  public:
    //Does not have its own getSomeParticularInfo() member function

  private:
    Steer* m_steer:
}
```

My question:

If I call getSomeParticularInfo. Will it come from Class B because it is the most recent derived class or does it come from the base class?

```
//Inside Class C constructor
C::C(){
  m_steer = getSomeParticularInfo();
}
```

Comment: However let me tell you, [this code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to understand this you need to understand the order of constructors here.  Before the body of `C::C()` is executed the constructor for the base type is executed.  In this case `B::B()`.  This is a recursive process so what you end up with is the constructors for `A`, `B` and `C` executing in order.

The constructor of a type in C++ will change the virtual method table to point to the version of a virtual method / override that it defines.  Hence

- `A::A()` will set the entry of `getSomeParticularInfo` to `A::getSomeParticularInfo`
- `B::B()` will set the entry of `getSomeParticularInfo` to `B::getSomeParticularInfo`

At the point `C::C()` has run both the constructor for `A` and `B` have run in that order.  Hence any calls to `getSomeParticularInfo` will resolve to `B::getSomeParticularInfo`

Note: In general I would avoid using virtual methods in the constructor.  It's generally speaking a bad practice because of the potential for confusion it creates.

Answer (score 1):

It will call `B::getSomeParticularInfo()`

And that function, as compiled will knowingly ignore `A::m_steer` and will not be aware of the existence of `C::m_steer`.

Answer (score 1):

It will be m_steer from B unless you explicitly call it from A like:

```
A::getSomeParticularInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you call `getSomeParticularInfo()` from C it will be the `m_steer` from B.

The only problem with the snippet above is that you shouldn't call virtual methods from constructors.